# Minimum connections needed for redis

Tags: nosql, redis

I see redis capable of  10s of thousands of connections. But why does it need so many? The connection(s) should be established by server, and only 1 server-redis connection should be sufficient for as many sessions as may be.

Is there something wrong with my logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right - one connection from server should be sufficient, BUT under "server" you have to imagine single instance of HTTP server running. On single machine there can me a lot of running server instances.

Then multiply this count of servers by count of individual machines using the same redis server and easily you are on very large numbers of connections.

Answer (score 1):

Kacer is right about the scenario. However, assume one more scenario.. where application keeps connection pool for performance reason.

Assume you are a proud owner of a Travel agency. However your agency have only 1 car and 1 driver.  But people are mad about your company and want to travel by your travel agency only.  So you need to send 100 people from Destination A to B.

```
 A  ———— B
```

Now, when first person goes second will have to wait until car returns after dropping 1st person. then 2nd will go and then 3rd. Although you have the fastest car and fastest driver but still it will take some time

Now, assume you have 50 cars and 50 drivers…  Would be much better right?

And what is unfortunately in first scenario your car met with an accident. You will have no other option. But if you manage connection pool you have 49 other alternates.